# Flutter - Get geocode address from coordinates

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, geocoding

I've implemented a reliable way of getting user lat,long coordinates in an app I'm creating, but can't seem to turn these coordinates into a placemark.

I'd also like to figure out what I need to use to print this data.

This is what I'm trying to get this data with:

```
List<Placemark> place = [];

void _getPlace() async {
  List<Placemark> newPlace = await _geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(_position.latitude, _position.longitude);
  print(newPlace);
  setState(() {
    place = newPlace;
  });
}
```

Thanks

Edit:

After CopsOnRoad's response, I'm getting this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: 

NoSuchMethodError: The method 'placemarkFromCoordinates' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: placemarkFromCoordinates(51.4998, -0.129)
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
#1      _NearbyPageState._getPlace 
package:tr/pages/nearby.dart:128
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _NearbyPageState._controlCard.<anonymous closure> 
package:tr/pages/nearby.dart:629
#3      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
#4      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:365
#5      TapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:312
#6      GestureArenaManager.sweep 
package:flutter/…/gestures/arena.dart:156
#7      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent 
package:flutter/…/gestures/binding.dart:222
#8      _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (p<…>
```

Comment: Have you added required permission in info.plist to use locations on iPhone?

Comment: Yeah, I have permissions in plist

Comment: What `newPlace` prints?

Comment: Something like [Instance of ‘Placemark’]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update:**
Use [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)

```dart
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);
```

---

**Old solution:**

You are already there, extra stuff that you need is:

```
String _address = ""; // create this variable

void _getPlace() async {
  List<Placemark> newPlace = await _geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(_position.latitude, _position.longitude);

  // this is all you need
  Placemark placeMark  = newPlace[0]; 
  String name = placeMark.name;
  String subLocality = placeMark.subLocality;
  String locality = placeMark.locality;
  String administrativeArea = placeMark.administrativeArea;
  String postalCode = placeMark.postalCode;
  String country = placeMark.country;
  String address = "${name}, ${subLocality}, ${locality}, ${administrativeArea} ${postalCode}, ${country}";
  
  print(address);

  setState(() {
    _address = address; // update _address
  });
}
```

Comment: Also, there may be a certain way to print this I'm not getting but I doubt that as you've got `print(address)` above in `_getPlace()`

Comment: Just fixed my issue after a `flutter clean`

Comment: how do you handle over_query_limit exception?

Comment: geocoding suports just english?! i want have address result with local languages. how can I do this?

Comment: Is there any free service to use map address to lat-long, lat-long to address and place autocomplete provider? Kindly suggest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Kamlesh The former is free but the later is paid.

Comment: Does it works for web application?

Comment: @VedantKakade No, it won't work on web.

Answer (score 6):

Placemark has been removed from [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) starting from version 6.0.0 and moved to [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding).

> Starting from version 6.0.0 the geocoding features (placemarkFromAddress and placemarkFromCoordinates) are no longer part of the geolocator plugin. We have moved these features to their own plugin: geocoding. This new plugin is an improved version of the old methods.

To translate latitude and longitude into an address with geocoding use

```dart
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use pub.dev flutter_geocoding

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_geocoding

OR

I have used swift 'GMSGeocoder' and java 'android.location.Geocoder' and applied it to flutter.I think it is more efficient than the library Geocode in pub.dev.

My example code

Geocode library java and swift add by yourself

java

```
 @Override
 public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);

        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), "samples.flutter.dev/latlng")
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {

                            double lat = call.argument("lat");
                            double lng = call.argument("lng");
                            result.success("return value lat and lng");

                        }
                );
    }
```

swift

```
override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let batteryChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "samples.flutter.dev/latlng",
                                                  binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        
        batteryChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            
            // Note: this method is invoked on the UI thread.
            guard call.method == "latlng" else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                return
            }
            
            self?.latlng(call,result: result)
        })
        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("")
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }


    private func latlng(_ call: FlutterMethodCall,result:FlutterResult) {
        if let args = call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, Any>,
           let lat = args["lat"] as? Double ,let lng = args["lng"] as? Double  {
            result("return latlng result" )
          } else {
            result(FlutterError.init(code: "bad args", message: nil, details: nil))
          }
    }
```

flutter

```
Future<void> _getBatteryLevel(double a, double b) async {
  String latlng;
  try {
    final String result = await const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/latlng').invokeMethod(
        'latlng', <String, dynamic>{"lat": a, "lng": b});
    latlng = result;
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    latlng = "Failed to get latlng level: '${e.message}'.";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

first, you have include lib -geolocator: ^3.0.1 in pubspec.yaml

```
///Get current location
  Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator();
  String latitude = "";
  String longitude = "";
  String address = "";
```

Try this solution -

```
///Call this function
 _fetchLocation() async {
    Position position = await _geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);///Here you have choose level of distance
    latitude = position.latitude.toString() ?? '';
    longitude = position.longitude.toString() ?? '';
    var placemarks = await _geolocator.placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
    address ='${placemarks.first.name.isNotEmpty ? placemarks.first.name + ', ' : ''}${placemarks.first.thoroughfare.isNotEmpty ? placemarks.first.thoroughfare + ', ' : ''}${placemarks.first.subLocality.isNotEmpty ? placemarks.first.subLocality+ ', ' : ''}${placemarks.first.locality.isNotEmpty ? placemarks.first.locality+ ', ' : ''}${placemarks.first.subAdministrativeArea.isNotEmpty ? placemarks.first.subAdministrativeArea + ', ' : ''}${placemarks.first.postalCode.isNotEmpty ? placemarks.first.postalCode + ', ' : ''}${placemarks.first.administrativeArea.isNotEmpty ? placemarks.first.administrativeArea : ''}';
    print("latitude"+latitude);
    print("longitude"+longitude);
    print("adreess"+address);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 try {
    await Geolocator()
        .placemarkFromCoordinates(value[0], value[1])
        .then((result) {
      Placemark placeMark = result[0];
      String name = placeMark.name;
      String subLocality = placeMark.subLocality;
      String locality = placeMark.locality;
      String administrativeArea = placeMark.administrativeArea;
      String postalCode = placeMark.postalCode;
      String country = placeMark.country;
      String address =
          "${name}, ${subLocality}, ${locality}, ${administrativeArea} ${postalCode}, ${country}";
      print(address);
      
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

With `Geolocator Plugin` new version (from version 6.0.0). Geocoding features (`placemarkFromAddress` and `placemarkFromCoordinates`) are no longer part of the geolocator plugin. This method have moved these features to their own plugin: [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)

Answer (score 2):

Future getLatAndlong() async{
cl = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition().then((value)=>value);

```
lat = cl.latitude;
long = cl.longitude;
_kGooglePlex =    CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(lat,long),
    zoom:14
);
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
    lat, long);
print("country"+placemarks[0].country!);
print("area"+placemarks[0].administrativeArea!);
print("locality"+placemarks[0].locality!);
print("sublocality"+placemarks[0].subLocality!);
print("postlocality"+placemarks[0].postalCode!);
print("street"+placemarks[0].street!);

setState(() {

  countrycurrent = placemarks[0].country!;
  localcurrent = placemarks[0].administrativeArea!;
  madinacurrent = placemarks[0].subLocality!;
  curren=countrycurrent+","+localcurrent+","+madinacurrent;
});
```

mymarker.add(
Marker(
infoWindow: InfoWindow(
title: placemarks[0].country! + "," +
placemarks[0].administrativeArea! +
"," + placemarks[0].locality!
),
draggable: true,

```
  icon:
  BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueOrange),

  markerId: MarkerId("4"),

  position: LatLng(lat, long)),
```

);}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).