# how to convert latitude and longitude in flutter using location

Tags: flutter, location

I want to convert latitude and longitude to address but I don't know how, here's the code I made:

```
 void dispose() {
  locationService.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

  return StreamBuilder<UserLocation>(
  stream: locationService.locationStream,
  builder: (_, snapshot) => (snapshot.hasData) ? Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Order"),
      actions: [
        IconButton(onPressed: () => logout(), icon: Icon(Icons.logout))
      ],
    ),
    body: ListView(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            
             Text("Latitude"
              ),
                Text("${snapshot.data!.latitude}"
              ),
              Text("Longitude"
              ),

                Text("${snapshot.data!.longitude}"
              ),
```

I want snapshot.data!.latitude and longitude to be addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding), and then bellow code,

```
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates("${snapshot.data!.latitude}", "${snapshot.data!.longitude}");
```

then,

```
Text("${placemarks[0].country}")
Text("${placemarks[0].administrativeArea}")
```

Comment: how to put the above code into body: ListView()

Comment: Container-> child listview-> children-> those text widget, put some height in container. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949432/flutter-get-geocode-address-from-coordinates

Answer (score 1):

You can use [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) to get address from latitude and longitude

```
List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(40.6971494, -74.2598717);
print(placemarks[0].country.toString() +
        "::" +
        placemarks[0].administrativeArea.toString() +
        "::" +
        placemarks[0].subAdministrativeArea.toString());
```

result

```
United States::New Jersey::Union County
```

Comment: how to put the above code into body: ListView()